# Intersection of a pointed cone and a hyperplane is a polytope?

Tags: convex-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry, convex-cone

Let $C = \text{cone}(u_1,\dots,u_m)$ for some $u_1,\dots,u_m \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{\textbf{0}\}$ be a finitely generated pointed cone. Let $H_0 := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \langle a,x \rangle = 0\}$ be a hyperplane such that $C \subseteq H_0^\geq$ and $C \cap H_0 = \{\textbf{0}\}$. For some $\delta > 0$, let $H_\delta := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \langle a,x \rangle = \delta \}$ and $C_\infty := C \cap H_\delta$.

[image]

I want to show that $C_\infty$ is a polytope. Since both $C$ and $H_\delta$ could be represented by a system of inequalities, so is $C_\infty$, which shows that it is a polyhedron. Now I just need to show that it is also bounded.

I was attempting a proof by contradiction, assuming that $C_\infty$ is not bounded, hence containing a ray $\{x + ty: t \geq 0\}$ for some $x \in C_\infty$ and $y \neq \textbf{0}$ (and in particular a point $q = x + ty, t > 0$ on this ray).  This should lead to $C \cap H_0$ contains more than just $\textbf{0}$, but I haven’t been able to show it so far. I know that $y$ as defined above should be in $H_0$, but that has not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

If $x\in H_\delta\cap C$, then $\epsilon x\in  H_{\epsilon\delta}\cap C$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

That is, if for some $y\in H_0\setminus\{0\}$ and all $t\ge 0$ holds $x+ty\in  H_\delta\cap C$, then also $\epsilon x  + ty\in H_{\epsilon\delta}\cap C$ for all $t\ge 0$ (the $\epsilon$ in the last term got absorbed into the $t$). Note that $C$ can be written as the union

$$C=\bigcup_{\epsilon \ge 0} (H_{\epsilon\delta}\cap C),$$

and so $\epsilon x + t y\in C$ for all $\epsilon > 0, t \ge 0$. But since $C$ is a  closed set, with $\epsilon\to 0$ we find $yt\in C$ for all $t\ge 0$. In particular, for $t>0$ and since $y\in H_0\setminus\{0\}$, we found $0\not= yt\in H_0\cap C$.

The crucial part is indeed that $C$ is closd, because the statement is wrong for open cones.

Comment: Just a comment: in $C=\bigcup_{\epsilon > 0} (H_{\epsilon\delta}\cap C)$, shouldn’t we have “$\supseteq$” instead of ‘$=$”, since the right hand side doesn’t contain the point $\textbf{0}$?

Comment: Also, just to be sure, is it correct to say that $yt$ is an accumulation point of $C$ because there is an infinite number of points in the sequence $(\epsilon x + ty)_n$ that are contained in any neighborhood of $yt$?

Comment: @JoshNg You are right. I fixed it, but in a different way: the union is now over all non-negative $\epsilon$. And yes, $yt$ is an accumulation point.